# R table function: how to sum instead of counting?

Tags: r, aggregate

Suppose I have data in an R table which looks like this:

```
Id  Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode
1   A     2     5     8       1     X       K
1   A     2     6     9       2     X       K
1   A     2     5     8       3     X       K
1   B     2     4     6       1     Y       L
1   B     2     3     4       2     Y       L
1   B     2     5     7       3     Y       L
2   C     2     5    11       1     X       M
2   C     2     5    11       2     X       L
2   C     2     5    11       3     X       K
2   D     2     8    10       1     Y       M
2   D     2     8    10       2     Y       K
2   D     2     5    7        3     Y       K
3   E     2     5    9        1     Y       M
3   E     2     5    9        2     Y       L
3   E     2     5    9        3     Y       M
3   F     2     4    7        1     Z       M
3   F     2     5    8        2     Z       L
3   F     2     5    8        3     Z       M
```

If I use the `table` function on this data like:

```
table(df$Category, df$Mode)
```

It will show me under each mode which category has how many observations. It's like counting the number of items in each category under each mode.

But what if I want the table to show under each `Category` which `Mode` earned how much `Profit` (sum or mean) and not the total count?

Is there any way to do this with the `table` function or another function in R?

Comment: You can sum and count this way: `tmp = aggregate(df$Category, by=list(Category=df$Mode), FUN=sum)` or  `tmp = aggregate(df$Category, by=list(Category=df$Mode), FUN=NROW)`  (notice "sum" is lowercase and "NROW" is all caps).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`.  By default, the `xtabs` gets the `sum`

```
xtabs(Profit~Category+Mode, df)
#           Mode
#Category  K  L  M
#       X 36 11 11
#       Y 17 26 28
#       Z  0  8 15
```

Or another `base R` option that is more flexible to apply different `FUN` is `tapply`.

```
with(df, tapply(Profit, list(Category, Mode), FUN=sum))
#  K  L  M
#X 36 11 11
#Y 17 26 28
#Z NA  8 15
```

---

Or we can use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' format. It is more flexible as we can specify the `fun.aggregate` to `sum`, `mean`, `median` etc.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Category~Mode, value.var='Profit', sum)
# Category  K  L  M
#1        X 36 11 11
#2        Y 17 26 28
#3        Z  0  8 15
```

---

If you need it in the 'long' format, here is one option with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Category' and 'Mode', we get the `sum` of 'Profit'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Profit= sum(Profit)) , by = .(Category, Mode)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility consists in using the `aggregate()` function:

```
profit_dat <- aggregate(Profit ~ Category + Mode, data=df, sum)
#> profit_dat
#  Category Mode Profit
#1        X    K     36
#2        Y    K     17
#3        X    L     11
#4        Y    L     26
#5        Z    L      8
#6        X    M     11
#7        Y    M     28
#8        Z    M     15
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `dplyr` for most data analysis:

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, Category, Mode) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(Profit), count=n())
```

https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html